# Javascript: unable to add delay and load functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a following code which displays the clicked image in the below div using pause `JS`. I wanted to added some delay during which i show a loader/spinner on screen for few seconds and then show the pic. But i am getting a problem, that when I click image loader appears for a sec(no matter the delay ms e.g. 5000) and then image loads in the browser, not there `div`, Below is my HTML code for section I am targeting.

```js
function showPic(whichpic) {
    var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

    placeholder.setAttribute("src",source);

    if (!document.getElementById("imageDescription")) return false;

    if (whichpic.getAttribute("title")) {
      var text = whichpic.getAttribute("title");
    } else {
      var text = "";
    }
    var imageDescription_p = document.getElementById("imageDescription_p");
    var imageDescription_d = document.getElementById("imageDescription_d");

    var imageDescription = document.getElementById("imageDescription");
    if (imageDescription.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
      imageDescription.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
      // imageDescription_p.textContent=prob;
      imageDescription_d.innerHTML=test
      imageDescription_d2.innerHTML=test1
    }
    document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display='block'

    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';


    // if (imageDescription_p.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
    //   imageDescription_p.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
    // }
    return false;
  }

  function preparePlaceholder() {
    if (!document.createElement) return false;
    if (!document.createTextNode) return false;
    if (!document.getElementById) return false;
    if (!document.getElementById("imagegallery")) return false;
    var placeholder = document.createElement("img");
    placeholder.setAttribute("id","placeholder");
    placeholder.setAttribute("src","./img/resources/neutral_1.jpg");
    placeholder.setAttribute("alt","your image goes here");
    placeholder.style.padding='20px'
    placeholder.style.marginBottom='50px'

    var description = document.createElement("p");
    description.setAttribute("id","description");

    var desctext = document.createTextNode("Choose an image");
    description.appendChild(desctext);

    var imageDescription= document.createElement('h1');
    imageDescription.setAttribute("id","imageDescription");

    var imageDescription_p= document.createElement('p');
    imageDescription_p.setAttribute("id","imageDescription_p");

    var imageDescription_d= document.createElement('div');
    imageDescription_d.setAttribute("id","imageDescription_d");

    var imageDescription_d2= document.createElement('div');
    imageDescription_d2.setAttribute("id","imageDescription_d2");


    var desctext = document.createTextNode("");
    imageDescription.appendChild(desctext);

    var heading= document.getElementsByTagName('h3')
    var gallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");

    // insertAfter(description,heading);
    insertAfter(description,gallery)
    insertAfter(placeholder,description);
    insertAfter(imageDescription,placeholder);
    insertAfter(imageDescription_p,imageDescription);
    insertAfter(imageDescription_d,imageDescription_p);
    insertAfter(imageDescription_d2,imageDescription_d);
  }

  function prepareGallery() {
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
    if (!document.getElementById) return false;
    if (!document.getElementById("imagegallery")) return false;
    var gallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");
    var links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for ( var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].onclick = function() {

      document.getElementById("imagegallery").style.display='none'
      document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display='none'


      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';

      // document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'none';
      // setTimeout(calculateResults, 2000);
      // e.preventDefault();
      // return setTimeout(showPic(this), 2000)
        // return showPic(this);
        setTimeout(()=>showPic(this),5000)
      }
    }
  }
    addLoadEvent(preparePlaceholder);
  addLoadEvent(prepareGallery);
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <h3>Select Images Below</h3>
    <ul id="imagegallery">
      <li>
        <a href="./img/team/t1.jpg" title="Black Man in Glasses" >
          <img src="./img/team/t1.jpg" alt="the band in concert" height="75px" width="75px" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="./img/team/t2.jpg" title="Black Man in Glasses" >
          <img src="./img/team/t2.jpg" alt="the band in concert" height="75px" width="75px" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="./img/team/t3.jpg" title="Brown Women">
          <img src="./img/team/t3.jpg" alt="the guitarist" height="75px" width="75px" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a
         href="./img/team/t4.jpg" title="White Women">
          <img src="./img/team/t4.jpg" alt="the audience" height="75px" width="75px" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="loading">
        <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
```

If you are getting confused by my version of code you can look at [here](https://domscripting.com/domsters/photos.html). I am using the same code and flow here, except that i want to implement loader/spinner and hide(ul images get hidden after click) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder element you are creating is being created in the document:

`var placeholder = document.createElement("img");`

You need to place a `div` in your html code where you want the image to display, then you can append the placeholder image to that `div`:

`document.getElementById('id of the div you insert').appendChild('block you want to insert')`

Comment: it was actually working before, after i made changes for settimeout and loader only then i faced these issues

Comment: are you saying that since placeholder is hidden i cannot display inside it/ modify it? once image is clicked I hide placeholder then get href from `a` and put it in the `img` and then set placeholder display to block.

Comment: In your html code you need a `<div id="image-goes-here"></div>`. Then you can `appendChild()` to place your image inside it. To remove you can use `innerHTML = ''`.

Comment: couldn't understand what you are trying to say, i tried but it does not work makes the already complicated code more complex